# Exclude elements for focusout event

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events, addeventlistener

I have a div that looks like this:

```
    <div class="whole-container" id="body">
  <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>">
  <div class="queryAndpostswitcher">
     <button id="logOut" name="logOut" title="Log Out From The Site"> <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i></button>
  </div>
</form>
  <div class="make_a_post" id="container">
    <div class="tabs">
      <button name="make_post" id="post"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Make a post </button>
      <button name="make_query" id="query"><i class="fa fa-question"></i> Make a query </button>
    </div>
    <div class="main-post" id="main-post">
      <textarea placeholder="Enter Your Post Here" minlength="5" onfocus="showButton();" id="postTextArea" onfocusout="makeEveryThingNormal(this.id)"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="main-query" style="display: none;" id="main-query">
      <textarea placeholder="Enter Your Query Here" minlength="5" onfocus="showButton();" id="queryTextArea" onfocusout="makeEveryThingNormal(this.id)"></textarea>
      <select name="askTo">
        <option> Friends </option>
        <option> Community </option>
        <option> Both</option>
      </select>
    </div>
        <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <label for="multimedia"> <i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i> Multimedia </label>
                <input type="file" id="multimedia" name="image" style="display: none;"/>
               <input type="submit" style="display: none;"/>
          </form>
          <div class="postingOptions">
        <button id="postButton"><i class="fa fa-tick"></i>Let's Go!</button>
      </div>
      </div>
```

It has two options either to post a post or a query. I have added the `onfocus` and `onfocusout` events.
And my script tags look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function showButton() {
    let container = document.getElementById("container");
    let postButton = document.getElementById("postButton");
    let otherPosts = document.getElementsByClassName("post");
    container.style.height = "30%";
    postButton.style.display = "block";
    for(let i=0;i<otherPosts.length;i++){
      otherPosts[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
  function makeEveryThingNormal (id) {
    let container = document.getElementById("container");
    let postButton = document.getElementById("postButton");
    let otherPosts = document.getElementsByClassName("post");
    postButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
      alert("Yahooo!");
    })
    container.style.height = "25%";
    postButton.style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById(id).value = "";
    for(let i=0;i<otherPosts.length;i++){
      otherPosts[i].style.display = "block";
    }

  }
</script>
```

So, what it does is it highlights only the posting div and hides other elements when the input is on focus. Now, what I should have been able to is to run a function when the button is clicked but when the button is clicked, the function doesn't work. So, if there is some function like:

```
if(button.isClicked===true){
do something;
}
```

Or if I could exclude some elements on `focusout`, the problem would be solved. But nothing seems to work. So, what should I do to make everything go fine? Please do answer!

Answer (score 0):

you can try adding the onclick as attribut to the button and give it a js function to run if it was click example:

```
 <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

also you can use JQuery .click and .on to capture the click event :

```
$( "#target" ).click(function() {
   alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
});
$( "#dataTable tbody" ).on( "click", function() {
   console.log( $( this ).text() );
});
```

and you can use the addEventListener to capture the click :

```
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function);
```

Comment: I didn't understand it well, Would you mind explaining. I don't know jQuery well!

Comment: The click event listener doesn't run. I have added that in the code

Comment: which button your trying to capture the click from ?

Comment: the .click will capture the click of an element whether it's an html tag, class or id, just passe it $('[tag, #id, or .class]').click(funtion); the function can be written there or you can put a function name to be called

Comment: also be sure to include jquery lib in the top of the html page and this should work

Answer (score 0):

Got everything to work by adding a setTimeout() function. My new code looks like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  function showButton() {
    let container = document.getElementById("container");
    let postButton = document.getElementById("postButton");
    let otherPosts = document.getElementsByClassName("post");
    container.style.height = "30%";
    postButton.style.display = "block";
    for(let i=0;i<otherPosts.length;i++){
      otherPosts[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
  function makeEveryThingNormal (id) {
    let container = document.getElementById("container");
    let postButton = document.getElementById("postButton");
    let otherPosts = document.getElementsByClassName("post");
    postButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
      alert("Yahooo!");
    })
    setTimeout(otherStuffs, 500);
    function otherStuffs () {
    //these things are to run when other areas are clicked!
    container.style.height = "25%";
    postButton.style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById(id).value = "";
    for(let i=0;i<otherPosts.length;i++){
      otherPosts[i].style.display = "block";
    }
    }

  }
</script>
```